# Angular 1.2.x ng-hide and ng-show css transition

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate

I have read the various docs and how-to sites on this, but no matter what I do, I cannot get a div being shown to show a css transition.

```
<div class="row reveal-animation" ng-show="partneradd.showEntitlements">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Entitlements</legend>
      stuff
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where the ng-show value is a boolean that is toggled to true by a button on the page.  This works fine.  But no transition.

Following some code found on the angular site, I am using this in my sass:

```
.reveal-animation.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transition: 2s linear all;
   transition: 2s linear all;
   opacity: 0;
 }

.reveal-animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

But nothing.  What did I do wrong here?

Edit:  I have indeed loaded the ng-animate module and injected it into my app.js

Comment: Maybe I'm missing how Angular works, but I don't see any `.ng-enter` or `.ng-enter-active` classes in your markup.

Comment: "The animate service will automatically apply two CSS classes to the animated element and these two CSS classes are designed to contain the start and end CSS styling. Both CSS transitions and keyframe animations are supported and can be used to play along with this naming structure." from https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ngAnimate

Answer (score 0):

hope it can help you, you can just add an class on hide and show like here it is on click

```
<div class="row reveal-animation" 
ng-class="{'foo':!partneradd.showEntitlements }" ng-show="partneradd.showEntitlements">
```

**An Simple example** :

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
  .controller('ctrl', function ($scope){
    $scope.bar = false;
    $scope.clicked = function(){
       $scope.bar = !($scope.bar);
    }
  });
```

```css
.myDiv{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
   -webkit-transition: 1s linear;
    /*to only change opacity*/
    /*-webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear*/
   -moz-transition: 1s linear;
   -o-transition: 1s linear;
   transition: 1s linear;
   opacity: 1;
}

.foo{
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
     <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
        <button ng-click='clicked()'>Click me to change class</button>  
        <div ng-class="{foo: bar}"  class='myDiv'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would work, but everything I read says this should not be necessary, that the ng-animate module handles that class assignment.  Is this not so?

Comment: Also, in my case I need to hook into the existing show/hide event and the css that angular uses to hide and show things.

Answer (score 0):

ng-show is working with `ng-hide` class (take a look [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/directive/ngShow) for additional info and supported classes):

```
.reveal-animation {
  -webkit-transition: 1s all linear;
   transition:all linear 1s;
   opacity:1;
 }

.reveal-animation.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```